# Android - How to properly parse a file consisting of bytes delimited with space?

Tags: java, android, parsing

New day, new problems.

I'm working on an Android app that gets a stream of raw bytes from a sensor. Each such packet is 19 Bytes long. In order to store that data, I use String.valueOf() as follows:

```
String str = String.valueOf(values[0]) + " ";

for (byte i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    str = str + values[i] + " ";
}
try {
    txtWriter.write(str);

} catch (IOException ioe) {
    Toast.makeText(ConnectActivity.this, "IOException occured.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Storing seems to give no troubles, since the written file is consistent with the data. However on retrieving the file afterwards as:

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
splitData = bufferedReader.readLine().split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i += 19) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
        currentArray[j] = splitData[i+j].getBytes()[0];

    }
    processRXData(currentArray);
}

private void processRXData(byte[] data) {

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    bb.put(data, 1, 18);

    **print**(bb.getShort(0), bb.getShort(2), bb.getShort(4));

    **print**(bb.getShort(12), bb.getShort(14), bb.getShort(16));
}
```

The printed values are not right.

For instance, the values `{1,98,1,-49,-3,37,-3,-11,-1,71,0,-111,-1,-12,-1,-3,-1,4,0}` are expected to give `{354,-561,-731}` and `{-12,-3,4}`

Current result however is `{12601,11565,11571}` and  `{11565,11565,12340}`.

I expect it to be the work of getBytes() but can't find any workaround. 
Is there any feasible solution available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.getBytes not the same as Bytes.toString. When you convert byte to string you receive number of chars, for example byte value 127 is 3 char ['1','2','7'] with byte codes [49, 50, 55]

```
    byte b = 127;

    System.out.println(b + ""); // 127
```

String "127".getBytes() returns this array [49, 50, 55]

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString("127".getBytes())); // [49, 50, 55]
```

To properly read value you need next code:

```
    byte[] bytes = "127".getBytes();

    String value = "";
    for (byte part : bytes) {

        value += (char)part;
    }

    System.out.print(value); // 127
```

If you want to receive byte value you need parse this string via

```
    byte b = Byte.parseByte(value);
```

Comment: Thanks, all I did was to change `splitData[i+j].getBytes()[0]` to `Byte.parseByte(splitData[i+j])` and I got the solution to a problem which had me puzzling for almost a day!