# Byte to String conversion data mismatch in Android BLE

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am integrating Bluetooth Low Energy in my application. The purpose of this module is, I have some hardware embedded devices. These devices are connected with the BLE hardware as well as it will notify some data to my application using BLE Notify API. This part is working fine.

**Problem:**

My problem here is the data is received as a byte array and for some reason, I want to convert it to a string. The message is transmitted based on the serial communication protocol.  While I convert from byte to string some data mismatch is happening.
I tried

```
byte[] receivedArray = intent.getByteArrayExtra(BLEConstants.EXTRA_DATA);
String data = receivedArray.getBytes() // Tried this way
String data = Arrays.toString(receivedArray );  // Tried this way
```

Then I again convert the string as byte array

```
byte[] b = string.getBytes();
byte[] b = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);  // tried another way
byte[] b = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16); // tried another way
byte[] b = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); // tried another way
```

But the resultant byte array is mismatching the initial byte array.

receivedArray  != b.
Anyone has the solution please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        String example = "This is an example";
        byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();

        System.out.println("Text : " + example);
        System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes);
        System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes.toString());

        String s = new String(bytes);
        System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + s);
```

> Output

```
Text : This is an example
Text [Byte Format] : [B@187aeca
Text [Byte Format] : [B@187aeca
Text Decryted : This is an example
```

This may helps you.

For More info refer [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-byte-array-to-string-in-java/).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem two days before. Refer here: [Android - How to properly parse a file consisting of bytes delimited with space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570221/android-how-to-properly-parse-a-file-consisting-of-bytes-delimited-with-space/37571097#37571097). Don't use getBytes(). Instead use Byte.parseByte(String)

Instead of

```
byte[] b = string.getBytes();
```

use

```
byte[] b = Byte.parseByte(data);
```

Comment: parseBye() retun only a single byte. Not a byte array.